# jQuery ajaxStart and Stop Not Firing

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with my code. I can't seem to get the .ajaxStart to work. There should be an easy fix for this, I'd appreciate any help you could provide. I know the ajax is working because I have a php file with a 3 second sleep and then an echo that is being correctly displayed by my success function.

Any thoughts?

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('#loading').hide();

$("#email_form").ajaxStart(function() {
            alert('test');
            });
send_mail();
});

function send_email() {
            $("#email").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var student_id = $("#student_id").val();
                var email_type = $("#email_type").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();
                var dataString = 'student_id=' + student_id + '&email_type=' + email_type + '&message=' + message;
                var url = 'process/conference_email.php';
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    data:dataString,
                    url:url,
                    success:function(data) {
                        toastr.success(data, 'Sent');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

This means that you should bind your handler to `document` instead:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   alert('test');
});
```

The `ajaxStart` event that jQuery will trigger will not have a specific target so you won't be able to bind it to your `#email_form` element.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It worked once I bound it to the document handler. Thank you so much!!